# Ошибка отображения safari

Tags: css, вёрстка, css3

Есть пример: http://jsfiddle.net/ywgycw1L/6/

Это выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
слева - safari 5.1.7, справа - firefox

Как сделать отображение одинаковым?

Блоку внутри (серый) требуется сохранить абсолютное позиционирование и трансформацию.

```
.outer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid red;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    top: -100%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: rotate(108deg) skew(-50deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(112deg) skew(-50deg);
    transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: В Safari Version 9.0.1 (11601.2.7.2) пример по ссылке отображается как на правой картинке.

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть эти два элемента еще в один родительский.И вот ему тоже укажите overflow: hidden; .Этому блоку пробуйте сначала прописать высоту и ширину,потому попробуйте убрать ширину.И вариант второй.Попробуйте у .outer убрать ширину

Comment: увы, не помогает

Comment: Данную проблему так и не решил. Пока в качестве временного решения, данную ошибку закрыл картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

На айпаде не воспроизвелось, поэтому отвечаю вслепую. http://jsfiddle.net/ywgycw1L/7/

у аутера добавьте правило

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Это тяжёлая артилерия, если результат устроит - можно попробовать чуть полегче (для браузера и железа)

```
-webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
```

или даже просто opacity(0.99999999);

Comment: Я тут подумал - если речь идёт о сафари под windows то тут фишка есть - это не настоящий сафари, проект этого браузера Эпл свернула, настоящий сафари не лажает так, как его windows-собрат.

Comment: Нет, в этом случае ошибка тоже воспроизводится